# Pandas HDF5 Showing Large Overhead per Observation

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

I'm experimenting with moving to a HDF5 based storage system using Pandas. I have several datasets for testing that are simple JSON lists, each row an observation of about 80B. All aggregated together, I'm working with ~100,000 observations. This would leave me to expect storage in the range of ~10MB.

Instead, I'm seeing 800MB.

This type of overhead can't be right, and I can only assume I'm fouling something up terribly.

Here's the snippet used to create the HDF5 store.

```
with pd.HDFStore('store.h5', complevel=9, compblib='bzip2') as store:
    for dataset in datasets:
        data = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(dataset.read()))
        store.append('data', data)
```

The data I'm processing can be seen as lists made up of:

```
[
    "ca2b3a75-c73e-45fa-b0c3-3fc50484fb15", 
    "2016-09-21T21:10:10Z", 
    "234"
]
```

Here's the output of info() for a 10,000 row slice of the data:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 10000 entries, 0 to 1029
Data columns (total 3 columns):
AWSS_ID      10000 non-null object
TIMESTAMP    10000 non-null object
VALUE        10000 non-null object
dtypes: object(3)
memory usage: 312.5+ KB
None
```

Comment: can you post an output of: `print(data.info())`?

Comment: I don't have the full table available, but I posted the info() output for a 10,000 entry slice.